# Creating dynamic FIlter classes of JSONField attributes for Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-filter, django-mysql

Let's consider below model as an example.

```
from django_mysql.models import JSONField
class Student(models.Model):
    standard = models.CharField(_('Standard'), max_length=10, null=True, blank=True, choices=STANDARD_CHOICES)
    extra = JSONField()

# example data in above field might be as below
# {"name": "Bob", "buys": "tesla", "country": "India"}
# {"name": "Sam", "buys": "lamborgini", "country": "England"}
# {"name": "Izzy", "buys": "tesla", "country": "Egypt"}
```

This is my JSONFieldFilter BaseClass for JSONField filter. [Inspired from here](https://gist.github.com/gjain0/b264562ba66067f85da7a55063cbfa64)

```
class JSONFieldFilter(SimpleListFilter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(JSONFieldFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        assert hasattr(self, 'title'), (
            'Class {} missing "title" attribute'.format(self.__class__.__name__)
        )
        assert hasattr(self, 'parameter_name'), (
            'Class {} missing "parameter_name" attribute'.format(self.__class__.__name__)
        )
        assert hasattr(self, 'json_field_name'), (
            'Class {} missing "json_field_name" attribute'.format(self.__class__.__name__)
        )
        assert hasattr(self, 'json_field_property_name'), (
            'Class {} missing "json_field_property_name" attribute'.format(self.__class__.__name__)
        )

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        field_value_set = set()
        for data in Student.objects.values_list(
                self.json_field_name, flat=True):
            if self.json_field_property_name in data:
                field_value_set.add(data[self.json_field_property_name])
        return [(v, v) for v in field_value_set]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            json_field_query = {"{}__{}".format(self.json_field_name, self.json_field_property_name): self.value()}
            return queryset.filter(**json_field_query)
        else:
            return queryset
```

And derived static filter class as below.

```
class ExtraFilter(JSONFieldFilter):
    title = _('Car bought')
    parameter_name = 'CarBought'
    json_field_name = 'extra'
    json_field_property_name = 'buys'
```

And then used above derived ExtraFilter class in the list_filter as below at the `StudentAdmin` class.

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('standard', ExtraFilter)
```

Now, above snippets works perfectly fine. But what I want to achieve is `'To have dynamic each extra's attribute filter'`.

I can just maintain list somewhere in solo model, where I can input the names of attributes like...`['buys', 'country']` (Idea is I can get list of active attributes name and use it get_list_filter method to create class on the fly)etc.

Right now, there's only `'Buys'` filter. Which will populate the choices of car bought from each student. But If `'country'` is added in the solo model, then 'country' filter should be added. There can be multiple/many attributes added by each student in the extra field.

So, only `'json_field_property_name'` needs to be taken dynamic and passed to new derived class to `list_filter`. Also we have `get_list_filter` method from `admin.ModelAdmin`, we can use that to pass on dynamically created class. But I'm not so sure how to create class on the fly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm at the right same point, and I believe django is already doing this dynamically, because 'list_filter' allows strings as the model fields to create the filters dynamically. The only difference here would be to create your new JSONFieldFilter instead for each param string desired to filter with. But I don't find where it does this magic arggggg

Comment: Right on point. Let me know here if you get to make any progress.